# Contact form 7 validation failed

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I use Contact Form 7 plugin in WordPress, just updated to the latest version (4.9). If you submit a form without filling up all required fields a validation error occurs, however, the error message appears on the top of the missed field and it does not let you to fill it up.

[image]

The field is not disabled, if I delete the error message element in developer tools I can click into the field and fill it up.

Comment: sounds like a css issue

Comment: Have you contacted the plugin developers for support? If the problem is with the plugin, then they are the ones in the best position to fix it.

Comment: The error message should fade out on mouse enter which is declared in the plugin's javascript file.

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have used that plugin in the past and never had any issues with it. It is most probably a CSS issue.

Try to find `.wpcf7-not-valid-tip` class inside the *style.css* file and modify it to your liking.

Here are the default styles that the plugin uses:

```
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
    color: #f00;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17190692)

Comment: Rewrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _wpcf7_unit_tag = $('form#booknow_popup').find('input[name="_wpcf7_unit_tag"]').val();

var data = new FormData();
data.append("_wpcf7_recaptcha_response",g_recaptcha_response);
data.append("_wpcf7_unit_tag", _wpcf7_unit_tag);

simply those fields are required or not fount so append it.
```